# Can't find a package for RankBoost

Tags: python, r, package, ranking-functions

I want to do ranking in R and I want to use the RankBoost algorithm. However, there seems to be no packages for R or even for python. The closes package is RankAggreg but that doesn't use the RankBoost algorithm. How can there not be an already written package for an algorithm that has been widely used for ranking problems?

What can I do in this case? Is writing the whole algorithm from scratch my best shot?

Thank you

Comment: [RankBoost+](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-019-05826-x) and python [implementation](https://github.com/rail-cwru/rankboostplus), paper has perhaps sufficient pseudo code to write in R.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just wanted to see if there indeed exists a package for it. Thanks.